# How can i create server side application for postgreSQL (for android app and no Firebase)

Tags: java, android, postgresql

I'm a beginner at java and i'm developing a big app the big issue is that i need a big database for which i should make a server side application(which i don't know how) to connect to Postgres. I did not find anything about making it and connecting it to PostgreSQL to Android Studio for instance.. I'm really confused and can't find anything about the topic. Excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to see this example https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Mysql is being used, but you could simple change the "jdbc driver" to connect with PostgreSQL

First change driver in pom.xml

this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and then replace the url in src/main/resources/application.properties with the connection info of your postgres instance.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
```

also add this line to the properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12007

On postgres user is a reserved keyword, so you have to change the name of the table that maps with User entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name = "users")
```

In this way you have the example working.

If not needed to do in Java, you can do it on other languages and frameworks, but the main idea would be to have an API and fetch or post data from/to.

I leave you some useful links to have more information

JDBC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity

PostgreSQL JDBC Driver : https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc

ORM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Hibernate, a Java ORM http://hibernate.org/orm/

REST: https://spring.io/understanding/REST

Comment: Well, keep in mind it's an example, but if you make the changes that I said, you will have an "API" of users that let you create new and fetch all users. Its only a starting point to do it in Java, but like I said, if you have more experience on the backend with another language or framework, may be more appropriate for you to do it with that.